# Does loading multiple json files in single test suit is a good practice in cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

Does loading multiple json files in single test suit is a good practice in cypress?
Something like this:

```
before(() => {
    cy.fixture('productCatalogData').then((datajson) => {
      recipeData = datajson.recipes;
      return recipeData;
    });
    cy.fixture('loginData').then((datajson) => {
      loginData = datajson;
      return loginData;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Are you using the fixture files across different test files or only for a single one?

Comment: Some files, I am using in all the test files (eg. loginData). Some files in single one (eg. productCatalogData) @jjhelguero

Answer (score 0):

If you need both the json files in one suite, I don't think there should be a problem using fixtures multiple times. However you can shorten the `cy.fixture()` code a bit like [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/fundamentals__fixtures/cypress/integration/load-fixtures-spec.js#L91):

```js
before(() => {
  cy.fixture('productCatalogData').as('productCatalogData')
  cy.fixture('loginData').as('loginData')
})

it('Access fixtures data', function () {
  // The test has to use "function" callback to make sure "this" points at the Mocha context
  //Access fixtures data using this.productCatalogData and this.loginData
})
```

But one thing to add here, cypress removes aliases after every tests. So if you have just one test inside the suite then `before()` will work fine, but if you have multiple tests you have to use `beforeEach()`.